# Why SQL Server complains about non existing column, if the actual SQL is not executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE name='RequireNamespaceClaim' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('DefaultBaseUrl'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE DefaultBaseUrl SET AuthenticationTypeId = at.AuthenticationTypeId
    FROM DefaultBaseUrl dbu
    JOIN (
        SELECT AuthenticationTypeId, CASE CodeName WHEN 'NATIVE' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END RequireNamespaceClaim 
        FROM AuthenticationType
    ) at ON dbu.RequireNamespaceClaim = at.RequireNamespaceClaim
END
```

Running it prints:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'RequireNamespaceClaim'.
```

However, running

```
SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE name='RequireNamespaceClaim' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('DefaultBaseUrl')
```

reveals that no such column indeed exists.

So, the `IF EXISTS` statement is `FALSE`, hence the body of the if-statement does not run. However, the error is still printed.

What is going on?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx for an explanation of deferred name resolution.

Comment: Your SQL server will parse the entire procedure in order to calculate the best way to execute it. It will do this before any execution actually takes place. You can fix it easily: remove the reference to the non-existent column, or create the column.

Comment: If you must have a query that can run whether a column exists or is missing, you can use dynamic sql, by storing the SQL in a `varchar` variable and calling `exec(@sqlcode)`.

Comment: This is not easy at all. The code is part of the upgrade script (actually, there is more to it, I just stripped most of it) and may be run several times. On the first pass the column may exist, but not on the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server compiles the entire query and checks it for validity.

At that time the column doesn't exist.

There is a command to run an SQL from a string which is not compiled.

Have a look at (I think that's the right one):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx